# What date format is this? Or is it even a date?

Tags: datetime

I'm working with a Drupal 8.3.6 setup done by someone else and I have a date format that doesn't make sense to me. I'm interacting with it thru MySQL Workbench.
The best I can tell,
1499287512 = Wed, 07/05/2017 - 23:02
and
1501079338 = Tue, 08/22/2017 - 06:25
BUT there's no guarantee of that.
In any event, 1499287512 and 1501079338 appear to be in a date placeholder; numbers like it appear in users_field_data.fields, created, changed, access, login.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are dates stored as [Unix timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which are essentially the number of seconds since midnight, January 1st, 1970 UTC (the epoch is 1970-01-01T00:00:00+00:00).

As far as Drupal is concerned, they are proper fields on those entities, either `TimestampItem`, `CreatedItem`, or `ChangedItem` fields.

Keep in mind that the timestamp always refers to that epoch and always is referenced to UTC; there is no real thing as a Unix timestamp in a local time zone.  When working with them in Drupal it is always best to use `DrupalDateTime` objects, and use it methods for computation (which will inherit from `\DateTime`).

Comment: Thank you, I used from_unixtime()  as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267564/convert-unix-timestamp-into-human-readable-date-using-mysql -- what do you mean about DrupalDateTime objects? You mean working with them w/in Drupal in PHP?

Comment: @seizethecarp `FROM_UNIXTIME()` is going to rely on the time zone of the MySQL server, not necessarily the user.  `DrupalDateTime` objects are for PHP.  It isn't really advisable to use database values directly; leverage the appropriate Drupal API.